# Get variable with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this in my htaccess

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^associato/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ associato.php?idassociato=$1 [QSA,L]
```

But when I try to go at:

http://www.mydomain.it/associato/1/a

the page associato.php is called correcty, but

```
$idassociato = $_GET['idassociato'];
echo $idassociato;
```

return nothing...did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to disable [multiviews](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_negotiation.html) on your server , try :

```
Options -Multiviews
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^associato/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ associato.php?idassociato=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Debian, please disable the MultiViews option.

See https://serverfault.com/questions/83380/apache-extensionless-urls-get-an-automatic-php-extension

The reason why you got this is that Apache will try `/associato.php` when you accessing `/associato/1/a`, thus dividing `/1/a` as pathinfo. But how it fails with 404 is far than I know.